# Where does Thunderbird store my setting?

Tags: backup, thunderbird

Can I backup my Thunderbird settings without the Emails and without its internal data? The Emails folder is too big and the emails not worth the effort. I'd like to put the important files under version control. I've already found `prefs.js` and `abook.mab`, but I don't know if storing these files alone suffices (i.e., can I use them on a new installation)? Are there more such files worth storing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [Profile backup page in mozillaZin (Mozilla Knowledge Base)](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_backup) for information about backing up your profile and all the important files, and restoring your profile after the new installation.

[The Thunderbird Profile folder page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird) contains detailed information about the Thunderbird Profile folder. You can see all the files and folders of your profile [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Files_and_folders_in_the_profile), with a detailed description of what each folder and file contains.

[Here is the table, anyway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZeQH.png):

[image]